# check if node represents directory in c++

Tags: c++, windows, directory, file-type

I have to list all directories in some folders in my application. To do so I've written something of this kind:

```
std::vector<std::string> FirefoxCleaner::_getDirs(std::string path) {
    std::vector<std::string>* dirs = new std::vector<std::string>();
    std::cout<<DT_DIR<<std::endl;
    DIR *dir = opendir(path.c_str());
    struct dirent *entry = readdir(dir);
    while (entry != NULL) {
        std::cout<<entry->d_name<<": "<<entry->d_type<<std::endl;        
        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            std::cout<<entry->d_name<<std::endl;
            //dirs.push_back(entry->d_name);
        }
        entry = readdir(dir);
    }

    closedir(dir);
    return *dirs;
}
```

I've commented push_back line because I don't need it for the moment (and I know it should be -> instead of . sign there). However though the result of this method is:

```
16
.: 24
..: 24
extensions: 24
lidv7pj1.default: 24
v0kmwatk.defaultextensions.ini: 24
```

As you can imagine extensions and lidv7pj1.default are in fact directories. How can I determine it?

Answer (score 0):

The `d_type` entry is a bitmask, so you need to check it using `&`:

```
if (entry->d_type & DT_DIR)
```

should solve this.

Comment: If all records have 24 then all of them have exactly the same bit representation so ini file is also considered as directory now :/